# java.util.Set.remove(Object o) - problem

Tags: java, collections

I must be missing something here... I have the following code and output. Can you see why `Category categoryToBeDeleted` is not being deleted from the category set of each book in `result`?

Thanks!!

Code:

```
List<Book> result = ... //get list from database

final Category categoryToBeDeleted = ... //get category from database

System.out.println("categoryToBeDeleted id: " + categoryToBeDeleted.getId() + " name: " + categoryToBeDeleted.getName());

for (Book book : result) {
    System.out.println("before remove :");
    for (Category category : book.getCategories()) {
        System.out.println("category id: " + category.getId() + " name: " + category.getName() + " equals: " + category.equals(categoryToBeDeleted));
    }
    System.out.println("-----------------------");

    book.getCategories().remove(categoryToBeDeleted);

    System.out.println("after remove :");
    for (Category category : book.getCategories()) {
        System.out.println("category id: " + category.getId() + " name: " + category.getName() + " equals: " + category.equals(categoryToBeDeleted));
    }
    System.out.println("-----------------------");

}
```

Output:

```
categoryToBeDeleted id: 10 name: cosmetics
before remove :
category id: 10 name: cosmetics equals: true
category id: 1 name: cleaning equals: false
-----------------------
after remove :
category id: 10 name: cosmetics equals: true
category id: 1 name: cleaning equals: false
-----------------------
before remove :
category id: 9 name: junk-2 equals: false
category id: 10 name: cosmetics equals: true
-----------------------
after remove :
category id: 9 name: junk-2 equals: false
category id: 10 name: cosmetics equals: true
-----------------------
before remove :
category id: 6 name: knick-knacks equals: false
category id: 4 name: baby equals: false
category id: 9 name: junk-2 equals: false
category id: 10 name: cosmetics equals: true
-----------------------
after remove :
category id: 6 name: knick-knacks equals: false
category id: 4 name: baby equals: false
category id: 9 name: junk-2 equals: false
category id: 10 name: cosmetics equals: true
-----------------------
```

P.S. Category contains:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Category) {
        Category thatCategory = (Category) obj;
        return this.id.equals(thatCategory.id);
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Javadoc**

[remove](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

boolean remove(Object o)

Removes the specified element from this set if it is present (optional operation). More formally, removes an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)), if this set contains such an element. Returns true if this set contained the element (or equivalently, if this set changed as a result of the call). (This set will not contain the element once the call returns.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your set is actually a `HashSet`.  Category isn't implementing `hashCode`.  As a result, when you go to remove the object, the object identifier is used as the hash code, and for each different object, even if it's semantically equivalent, it ends up using a different hash code, looking in the wrong place in the hash set and not finding the appropriate matching object.

Add

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id.hashCode();
}
```

to `Category` and all should be well.

The requirement to override `hashCode` can be read in the [JavaDoc for java.lang.Object#equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method
>   whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general
>   contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must
>   have equal hash codes.

As this text implies, the [JavaDoc for hashCode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) covers this in more detail.

Whilst the JavaDoc for `remove` could perhaps be clearer on the subject, it only references `equals` as part of the specification for which object it will remove - it doesn't say that `equals` is the only thing it will use.

Finally, if you're using Eclipse, there's a warning you can turn on which will warn you if you override `equals` without overriding `hashCode` or vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks! First, your solution works. Now, I have added at the bottom of my post the javadoc for Set.remove(Object o).... how do I get from there the requirement to override hashcode()? It only says the method uses equals().

Comment: I've added some more detail about that.

Comment: Thank you! It was very informative. And thanks for the Eclipse tip.

Answer (score 2):

If you override equals(), you should override hashCode() also.